# Знаки после запятой. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, форматирование

Нужно вернуть число в формате `2.00`

При написании подобной функции:

```py
a = float('{:.2f}'.format(a))
```

0 после запятой не возвращаются.

Как поступить?

Comment: число "в формате 2.00"  - это строка.

Comment: Так зачем же Вы преобразовываете обратно в `float`? Вы теряете форматирование. Делайте так: `a = 2; print(f'{a:.2f}')`.

Answer (score -1):

Также можно сделать с помощью `round()`.
Требуются только 2 аргумента.

Пример:

```py
x = 12.123123
print(round(x, 1))

// 12.1
```

Comment: Видимо, вы неправильно поняли вопрос

Comment: Согласно вопросу нужно `2.00` вернуть, а не `2.1` ))